# How to append this JavaScript array object to another JavaScript array object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have this Javascript json array object;

```
var dataJson=[ [{v:1},{v:90}],[{"v":2},{"v":"33.7000"}] ];
```

I want to append this array object `dataJson` to another object such that it looks like this;

```
var chartObject = {"cols": [
    {id: "t", label: "t_label", type: "number"},
    {id: "s", label: "s_label", type: "number"} 
], "rows": [
    {c: 
        [{v:1},{v:90}] //dataJson[0]
    },
    {c: 
        [{"v":2},{"v":"33.7000"}] ////dataJson[1]
    }
]};
```

How do I use a for loop to insert `dataJson` elements into `chartObject`? I am sorry I am quite new to javascript and can't even produce some starting code. Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: google about javascript array push. `chartObject.push(dataJson)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
...
  ], "rows": dataJson.map(function(row) {return {c:row};})
};
```

Comment: My deepest apologies for saying your answer did not work just now. It worked perfectly. Thank you very much for your expert answer and time. 

It is an elegant and short answer. But I have problems understanding it now as I am a newbie. Will study this short line carefully.

Wish I could vote your answers a few times more to apologize for the earlier comment.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the code? It is short and yet hard to understand. But it works.

Comment: `.map` just applies the function you give it to each element in the array. In this case, it simply returns an object that "wraps" the row.

Comment: Is this programming style related to functional programming?

Answer (score 1):

Using the simple and clean way:

```
var chartObject = {"cols": [
    {id: "t", label: "t_label", type: "number"},
    {id: "s", label: "s_label", type: "number"} 
]};

var dataJson=[ [{v:1},{v:90}],[{"v":2},{"v":"33.7000"}] ];

chartObject["rows"] = [];   // start with empty array

// iterate over first dataJson array
for(var i = 0, len = dataJson[0].length; i < len; i++){ 
  // push in array `c` mapped to the i-th element of dataJson[0]
  chartObject["rows"].push({c : dataJson[0][i]["v"]});
}

console.log(chartObject);
```

#### **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/bufozudi/3/edit?js,console)**

<sup>Ignore those `[object Object]` in DEMO</sup>

**Sample Output:**

```
{
    cols: [{
        id: "t",
        label: "t_label",
        type: "number"
    }, {
        id: "s",
        label: "s_label",
        type: "number"
    }],
    rows: [{
        c: 1
    }, {
        c: 90
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript objects are pretty amazing things. Just define a new field in `chartObject` as an array, and then `push` whatever json data you want into it. It looks you want rows to be an array of objects which have an identifier for each json object, but unless you explicitly want to name each dataJson with a string, then just use an indexed array:

```
chartObject["rows"] = [];

for(var i = 0; i < dataJson.length; i++) {
    chartObject["rows"].push(dataJson[0]);
}
```

Now you can access each piece of data with:

```
chartObject["rows"][index]
```

And each field in the data with:

```
chartObject["rows"][index]["v"]
```